# Right approach for updating linked .js files to already published add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Add-in is already published on AppSource.
There is a new feature or bug fix implemented in .js file linked in `taskpane.html` of the official version.

Should an update to add-in be done using Partner Center or a simple update of linked .js file is acceptable?

We are using simple content update of linked .js files approach and we are facing 2 problems:

1. Some users need to clear cache manually to force Excel to download updated .js file.
2. Some users report that custom function call in workbook was expanded with prefix `_xldudf_`. (premise is that Excel recognizes a change of official assets and thus treats it as insecure)